# Select an icon in a button android

Tags: android, button

all... I would like to ask how can choose an icon in OnClickListener()?

1. When I press a button, there will come out a dialog/interface with many icons.
2. After I choose the icon what I want, then the dialog will close, and the icon which I had selected will show at the button.

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

When ever U selected one image from Dialog box then each click enable one flag whether its true or not then after dismissing dialog box simple check the flag if its true then based on flag simply set selected image from dialog and set on your button.

If you have any clarification let me know..or add some code here..so that i will modify once..

Answer (score 0):

try this code. it work as per your requirement.

```
package com.example.demotext;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HomePage extends Activity {

    int drawables[] = { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher_ };
    String drawables_[] = { "R.drawable.ic_launcher", "R.drawable.ic_launcher_" };
    private Button btn1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        HomePage.this);
                builder.setTitle("Select Your Account");

                builder.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(HomePage.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, drawables_),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                btn1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
                                    .getDrawable(drawables[which]));

                            }
                        });

                builder.show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: TQVM... I will try it... ^^